# Google Analytics setup not working

Tags: 7, google-analytics

I am trying to setup a Google Analytics property. I have done this before and have had no problems. However this time I am setting it up though the drupal module rather than manually inserting the code. 
I have my tracking ID and everything filled out, and I inspect the page and I can see the tracking code is installed.
However my tracking code isnt being picked up by Google Analytics. This is what it says:

```
Status: Tracking Not Installed
```

I have enabled debugging for the module, and all seems to be sending correctly. Here is the log:

```
Initializing Google Analytics. analytics_debug.js:10
Running command: ga("create", "UA-49353541-2", "auto") analytics_debug.js:10
Creating new tracker: t0 analytics_debug.js:10
Auto cookieDomain found: "carbonfunding.co.uk" analytics_debug.js:10
Running command: ga("send", "pageview") analytics_debug.js:10

Sent beacon:
v=1&_v=j30d&a=1343148915&t=pageview&_s=1&dl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.carbonfunding.co.uk%2F&ul=en-us&de=UTF-8&dt=Carbon%20Funding%20%7C%20Th…_u=MCCAAEQAI~&jid=&cid=2073925826.1413195127&tid=UA-49353541-2&z=327379316

 analytics_debug.js:10
_j1              (&jid)  analytics_debug.js:10
adSenseId        (&a)   1343148915 analytics_debug.js:10
apiVersion       (&v)   1 analytics_debug.js:10
clientId         (&cid) 2073925826.1413195127 analytics_debug.js:10
encoding         (&de)  UTF-8 analytics_debug.js:10
flashVersion     (&fl)  15.0 r0 analytics_debug.js:10
hitType          (&t)   pageview analytics_debug.js:10
javaEnabled      (&je)  1 analytics_debug.js:10
language         (&ul)  en-us analytics_debug.js:10
location         (&dl)  http://www.carbonfunding.co.uk/ analytics_debug.js:10
screenColors     (&sd)  24-bit analytics_debug.js:10
screenResolution (&sr)  1920x1080 analytics_debug.js:10
title            (&dt)  Carbon Funding | The ECO people analytics_debug.js:10
trackingId       (&tid) UA-49353541-2 analytics_debug.js:10
viewportSize     (&vp)  1903x955
```

I read that it can take up to 72 hours before Google will pick up the tracking code, but I also read that at least the real-time view should be picking myself up on the site. I have also disabled do-not-tack everywhere and no prevail.

Why is this the case?

Thanks,
Darryl

Answer (score 1):

Adding Google Analytics using the module is not difficult. Please check this YouTube Video ["Adding Google Analytics"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5UleWXsDxr0) it will walk you on the process of how to set-up your Google Analytics on your Drupal site. In addition it will to provide you the steps on how to set-up this video will give useful information about the different setting.

If you want to make sure that your website contain the Google Analytics you can check the output of your website (as an anonymous) and you should have something similar to this...

Usually takes few minutes to Google Analytics to recognize your website.

```
<script>
  (function(i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
    i["GoogleAnalyticsObject"] = r;
    i[r] = i[r] || function() {
      (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
    }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date();
    a = s.createElement(o), m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
    a.async = 1;
    a.src = g;
    m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
  })(window, document, "script", "//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js", "ga");
  ga("create", "UA-xxxxx-1", "auto");
  ga("send", "pageview");
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, I have setup analytics to a few websites previously without issues. The data from yesterday is showing, but still Analytics says my code is not installed and the real-time functionality isn't working.